# setting smtp server in php geekmail

Tags: php

http://github.com/NeilCrosby/multi-level-vcards/blob/master/via-email/geekMail-1.0.php

That's a link to the class. How can I set the smtp server?

My current code looks like:

```
require_once( 'assetform/geekMail-1.0.php' );
$geekMail = new geekMail();
$geekMail->setMailType('html');
$geekMail->from('xx@gmail.com', 'no-reply');
$geekMail->to('xx@gmail.com');
$geekMail->subject('Request');
$geekMail->message('this is a test email.');
$geekMail->attach($path.'1287448945.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of that class, there is no public setter for the `$_smtpHost` variable.  You will either need to add one, or you can modifiy the geekMail-1.0.php file and change line 105 to contain your smtp server.

You will also need to make a public setProtocol method, or change `$_protocol` on line 97 from 'mail' to 'smtp'.  This variable is being used to tell the class which protocol to use.

Comment: I did that.. but it was still not using that SMTP server. Any clues? Check out line 1391, whats that?

Comment: Looks like there is one other variable you need to change, I updated my answer.  Line 1391 is a function called by _spoolEmail() based on the `$_protocol` variable.